# Submitting HTML data to a google App Engine MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-app-engine

I have been trying to create a simple web form that will be used to submit data to a Google App Engine database that uses MySQL. The database is connecting fine and the try catch statement seems to be working properly. The problem is that when i click the submit button, the data is not being committed into the database. Any help would be much appreciated, I'm sure there is just some small error that i am overlooking.

HTML form

```
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="connection.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                         <label for="patientName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Patient Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="Name" class="form-control" id="patientName" name="patientName">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                         <label for="Address1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address 1</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" rows='3' id="Address1" name="Address1"></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                         <label for="Address2" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address 2</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" rows='3' id="Address2" name="Address2"></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                         <label for="Address3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address 3</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" rows='3' id="Address3" name="Address3"></input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                         <label for="postCode" class="col-sm-2 control-label">PostCode</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postCode" name="postCode">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                         <label for="symptoms" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Symptoms</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" rows='5' id="symptoms" name="symptoms"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                         <label for="contactNumber" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Contact Number</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="Tel" class="form-control" id="contactNumber" name="contactNumber">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Log Call Details</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

PHP connection file

```
<?php

use google\appengine\api\users\User;
use google\appengine\api\users\UserService;

try {
$db = new pdo('mysql:host=111.111.111.11:3306;dbname=MyDB',
'root',
'password'
);

$patientName = $_POST["patientName"];
$address1 = $_POST["Address1"];
$address2 = $_POST["Address2"];
$address3 = $_POST["Address3"];
$postCode = $_POST["postCode"];
$symptoms = $_POST["symptoms"];
$contactNumber = $_POST["contactNumber"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO patient (patientName, patientAddress1, patientAddress2, patientAddress3, patientPostcode, PatientSymptoms, patientPhoneNumber)
VALUES ($patientName, $address1, $address2, $address3, $postCode, $symptoms, $contactNumber)";


$db->execute($sql);


} catch (PDOException $ex) {
echo "Could not connect to the database.";
exit;
}

$db = null;
echo "Woo-hoo!";
?>
```

I should probably also mention that the HTML page is using bootstrap.

Comment: You never execute your query.

Comment: So how do i execute this then. I'm new to PHP so I'm not sure how to execute this query.

Comment: There are [several methods](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php).

Comment: I tried a couple of those Jay but they didn't seem to work for some reason.

Comment: You should pick one, try it and then we could work through troubleshooting.

Comment: the first one i tried was `$sql->execute();` but it said that it needed to be cast on an object which lead me to try `$db->execute($sql);`. This didn't give any errors but still didn't commit anything to the database

Comment: Change your code above to reflect that, then we can work from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70258/discussion-between-samman-and-jay-blanchard).

Comment: I am unable to enter chat from my current location @SamMan

Comment: That's no problem Jay, Thank you very much for taking the time to help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code snippet below, It works, I did not used $_POST data but hard-coded values, Hope it helps !

more infos:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

```
$username="test12";
$role="test1";
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (username, role) VALUES (:username, :role)";
$conn = new pdo('mysql:host=127.0.0.1:3306;dbname=home',
'root',
'password'
);
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':username'=>$username, ':role'=>$role));
```